# How to fetch first 10 key value HashMap in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, get, hashmap

i have hashmap like this:

```
{apple, 20}, {nanas,18}, {anggur, 12},...........
```

my hashmap already sorting descending by value. and i want to get 10 element from first element hashmap.

can anyone help me ?

Comment: Just use a simple loop over the Entryset?

Comment: "my hashmap already sorting descending by value" hashmap doesn't preserve any order. If you are able to sort it you are doing it by probably using other structures like lists. In that case why not simply iterate over first 10 elements from such list? If that is not the case please clarify.

Comment: `HashMap` cannot be sorted as it has no order. Therefore there is no "first" `10`. No "last" `10`. This question makes no sense.

Comment: Pretty sure HashMaps are unordered. They don't have a "first 10 elements".

Answer (score 4):

If you use java 8, I would go with:

```
List<MyKeyType> keys = map.entrySet().stream()
  .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
  .sorted()
  .limit(10)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How it works:

1. entrySet().steam() - take map's entry set, and make a stream of its values.
2. map() - take the key value from the Map.Entry and pass it further down the stream
3. sorted() - if the class implements Comparator interface it'll be used by default, or you can provide your own implementation as required.
4. limit(10) - limit the numer of objects to 10.
5. collect the sorted 10 values into a list.

sorted() method takes an optional Comparator parameter, where you can provide custom sorting logic if required.

Comment: So would I. :-)

Comment: Since the map already appears to be sorted, this can be simplified to a less verbose - 
List<String> keys = sortedMap.keySet().stream()
                                .limit(10)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 2):

Since your map already sorted, we can get first 10 key-values as a new map like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> res = map.entrySet().stream()
        .limit(10)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

If your map not sorted, we can go with:

```
Map<String, Integer> res = map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((o1, o2) -> o2.getValue() - o1.getValue())
        .limit(10)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)** **in order to retain the order of the elements** (i.e., insertion order) and you can refer the below code to retrieve the first 10 elements from the loaded map object:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
//Load your values here
Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
String[] keysArray = keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]);
for(int i=0; i<keysArray.length && i<10;i++) {
    System.out.println(map.get(keysArray[i]));
}
```

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` maintains insertion order or optionally access order — not descending order by value.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the map’s `entrySet()` into a list, sort it by `getValue()` and take the 10 entries with greatest value.